# How to remove Google Chrome window border on Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, opera, microsoft-edge, border

As you can see on screenshot Google Chrome Browser (Version 46.0.2490.86 m) has 1px white border around on Windows 10 Build 1511. I suppose it's a native browser interface border, not depending from web page opened. Is there any chance to remove this border to get clean design like Edge and Opera have?

Screenshot:
White border [image]
Zoomed [image]